# Allow antd upload component to show progress bar then remove item after upload

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using the ant design uploader component.  This all works, however if the file fails to upload for any reason it shows the upload file in red underneath.

What I want to achieve is the file should show while it is uploading (as the progress is shown) then once it has finished, regardles of the outcome (success or fail) it should then not show the file.

I have tried to manipulate the filelist, however when this is set on the component I no longer get the file progress.

[image: Example of what is happening]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to work this one out, you have to manipulate the fileList yourself and also handle the upload progress.  This is what I came up with...

```
<Dragger 
    name='CertificateFile' 
    multiple={false} 
    onChange={SingleFileUploadOnChange} 
    customRequest={SingleCertificateFileUploadProcessFile}
    showUploadList={FormState.SingleCertFileUploading}
    fileList={fileList}
>
```

```
const [FormState, SetFormState] = useState({
    FormSubmitting: false,
    SingleCertFileUploading: false,
});
     
const [fileList, setFileList] = useState([]);

const SingleFileUploadOnChange = (info) => {
    const FileFound = fileList.some(el => el.name === info.file.name);
    if (!FileFound){
        let NewFileItem = {
            uid: info.file.uid,
            name: info.file.name,
            status: info.file.status,
            percent: 0,
            url: ""
        };
        setFileList(prevState => ([...prevState, NewFileItem]));
    } else {
        // update progress
        const UpdatedFileList = fileList.map(obj => {
            if (obj.name === info.file.name){
                return {...obj, percent: info.file.percent}
            }
        })
        setFileList(UpdatedFileList);
    }

    SetFormState({...FormState, SingleCertFileUploading: true});

    if (['done','error'].includes(info.file.status)){
        var filtered = fileList.filter((el) => { return el.name != info.file.name; }); 
        setFileList(filtered);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the following example

You can set `showUploadList` to `true` if it is uploading the file and `false`   if it has uploaded successfully or when file upload fails

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { InboxOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { message, Upload } from 'antd';

const { Dragger } = Upload;

const App = () => {
  const [showupload, setShowupload] = useState(false);

  const props = {
    name: 'file',
    multiple: true,
    action: 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76',
    
    onChange(info) {
      setShowupload(true);
      const { status } = info.file;
      if (status !== 'uploading') {
        console.log(info.file, info.fileList);
      }
      if (status === 'done') {
        message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully.`);
        setShowupload(false);
      } else if (status === 'error') {
        message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
        setShowupload(false);
      }
    },

    onDrop(e) {
      console.log('Dropped files', e.dataTransfer.files);
    },
  };

  return (
    <Dragger {...props} showUploadList={showupload}>
      <p className="ant-upload-drag-icon">
        <InboxOutlined />
      </p>
      <p className="ant-upload-text">
        Click or drag file to this area to upload
      </p>
    </Dragger>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Output:

[image: GIF]

Comment: If you then uploaded a second file would both files show?

Comment: While this works for showing and hiding the file, if the first file fails to upload and a second file is selected ou then get both files show up when setting the value to true

Answer (score 0):

I got a single-line solution for the problem that shows all the previously uploaded or failed files when the user tries to upload a file.
It might not work in all scenarios.

There is a *prop* called **fileList** that preserves all the uploaded or unuploaded files.
You just need to vacate the content of the **fileList** array by assigning its *length* to **0**.
It worked well for me.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button, notification, Upload, UploadProps } from "antd";
import { UploadOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

const UploadFunc: React.FC = () => {

  const props: UploadProps = {
    name: "file",
    action: `${your_api}/---`,
    
    onChange(info: any) {
      console.log("Before", info.fileList);

      if (info.file.status !== "uploading") {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => {
          console.log(e.target?.result);
        };
        reader.readAsText(info.file.originFileObj);
      }
      if (info.file.status === "done") {
        info.fileList.length = 0; // this line worked for me
        if (info.file.response.status === "error") {
          notification.error({
            message: `${info.file.name} file couldn't upload! Accounts already exists...`,
          });
        } else {
          notification.success({
            message: `${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully!`,
          });
          
        }
      } else if (info.file.status === "error") {
        info.fileList.length = 0; // // this line worked for me
        notification.error({
          message: `${info.file.name} file upload failed!`,
        });
      }

      console.log("After", info.fileList);
    },
    progress: {
      strokeWidth: 5,
      showInfo: true,
    },
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Upload {...props} accept=".xlsx, .csv" showUploadList={true}>
          <Button type="default" icon={<UploadOutlined />}>
            Upload File
          </Button>
      </Upload>
    </>
  );
};

export default UploadFunc;
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

in my project, I use fileList and filter by success status in onChange:

```
...
// add fileLis state and insert to Upload props
const [fileList, setFileList] = useState([]);
...
onChange(info) {
    ...
    // add end of onChange
    setFileList(info.fileList.filter((item) => item.status !== 'success'));
},
...
```

Depending on how to implement onChange, you can move the codes I have written.
But this is how it works. One of my friends also used this method in his answer.